# How to resolve the issue of repeatedly sending text message in an intruder alarm

Tags: arduino

This code is meant to be useful for detecting an intruder at a particular time interval, then it turns on 2 led's and a buzzer and then send a text message to the pre-programmed number. But the challenge I'm facing is that when the system comes on the pir sensor keeps sending a logic 1 and that in turn makes the gsm module to keep sending text message even when no intruder is in range also immediately the scheduled time elapses the sensor then again sends a logic 1 before finally going off. Secondly the text message I receive shows Content not support. Please I'm really in need of help I'm confused and I don't know what to do anymore.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM800(3, 2);
Time t;
DS3231 rtc(SDA, SCL);
String textForSMS;
int calibrationTime = 45; 
int PirSensor = 12;
int LedSensorPin = 13;
int Buzzer = 11;
int LedPowerPin = 9;
int Power   =  6; // 5V of sensor connected to pin6
int val     =0;

const int OnHour = 23;
const int OnMin =  19;
const int OnSec = 0;

const int OffHour = 23;
const int OffMin = 25;
const int OffSec = 0;


void setup() {
  
randomSeed(analogRead(0)); 
Serial.begin(9600);
SIM800.begin(19200);
rtc.begin();
Serial.println("Logging Time Completed ");
pinMode(PirSensor, INPUT);
pinMode(Buzzer, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LedSensorPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(LedPowerPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(Power,     INPUT);
digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);
delay(5000); //Wait for 5sec

}

void loop() {
  t = rtc.getTime();
Serial.print(t.hour);
Serial.print("hr, ");
Serial.print(t.min);
Serial.print("min. ");
Serial.print(t.sec);
Serial.print("sec");
Serial.println(" ");
delay(1000);


if(t.hour == OnHour && t.min == OnMin && t.sec == OnSec){
  analogWrite(Power, 255);       // Turn ON the Sensor
  digitalWrite(LedPowerPin, HIGH);
  Serial.print("calibrating sensor ");
      for(int i = 0; i < calibrationTime; i=i+1){
      Serial.print(".");
      delay(1000);
      }
      Serial.println(" done");
      delay(50);
      Serial.println("Sensor Activated");
      

}
else if(t.hour == OffHour && t.min == OffMin && t.sec == OffSec) {
  analogWrite(Power,     0);       // Turn OFF Sensor
  digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);       // Turn OFF LED 
  digitalWrite(LedPowerPin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(Buzzer, LOW);
  Serial.println("Sensor Deactivated");
}

val = digitalRead(PirSensor); 
if ( val == HIGH){
  textForSMS = "\Intruder Detected!";
  digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, HIGH);
  //digitalWrite(Buzzer, HIGH);
  //delay(10000);
  //digitalWrite(Buzzer, LOW);
  sendSMS(textForSMS);
  Serial.println(textForSMS);
  Serial.println("message sent.");
  delay(8000);
  }
  
  else{
  //digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);
  //Serial.println("No Intruder Detected");
  digitalWrite(LedSensorPin, LOW);
  //delay(1000);  //delay for 1 sec;
}
}

void sendSMS(String message)
{
 SIM800.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
 delay(1000);
 SIM800.println("AT+CMGS=\"+2349037557071\"");
 delay(1000);
 SIM800.println(message);
 delay(1000);
 SIM800.println((char)26);
 delay(1000);
 SIM800.println();
 delay(100);
 
 
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get 1 variable to be for help. I'll name it help just to show. This will make so the text msg will be sent only first time after change of state from low to high.

```
If (Val == high) {
     help ++;
}else if (Val == low){
    Help = 0;
}
If (help == 1) {
  textForSMS .....
  ..........................
}
```